# Why would the default Initialization fail when copy constructor is deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone explain to me why the below does not compile?  I'm not sure why the compiler thinks I'm invoking the copy constructor.

```
struct test {
  const int index;
 private:
  test(const test&) = delete; // comment out this line and voila.
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  test arg{1};
  return arg.index;
}
```

GCC fails with this message (reproducible in http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:8:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘test::test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   test arg{1};
             ^
main.cpp:8:13: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:4:3: note: test::test(const test&) <deleted>
   test(const test&) = delete;
   ^
main.cpp:4:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const test&’
```

Comment: The compiler isn't thinking that. Rather, it cannot find any matching constructor, which is what it's telling you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have two questions here.  The title asks about *default-initialization*, and your code uses *list-initialization*.

---

You were relying on list initialization, not default initialization, and specifically you are trying to get aggregate initialization.  The rules for that are found in 8.5.4p3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered.  The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7).  If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

and in 8.5.1:

> An  aggregate  is  an  array  or  a  class  (Clause  9)  with  no  user-provided  constructors  (12.1),  no  private  or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).
>
> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified in 8.5.4, **the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order.**

That's exactly what you want, but having a "user-provided constructor" disables that.  This is not the same as a "user-declared constructor", but some compiler writers may have confused the two (see [@dyp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23304770/103167)).

As far as I know, there's no way to explicitly enable aggregate initialization for a type that isn't an aggregate.  However you *can* work around this.  Make your type an aggregate, and disable copy-construction another way:

```
struct test
{
  const int index;
  struct nocopy { nocopy() = default; nocopy(const nocopy&) = delete; } copy_disabled;
};
```

This works because 12.8p11 says:

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public member of its class.  A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class X is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> ...
>
> - a  non-static  data  member  of  class  type `M` (or  array  thereof)  that  cannot  be  copied/moved  because overload resolution (13.3),  as applied to `M`'s corresponding constructor,  results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,

Note however that you can't just inherit from `boost::noncopyable`, because aggregates cannot have base classes.

---

The case dealing with default initialization is a bit easier.  Recall the condition for having a compiler-declared default constructor:

- There are no user-declared constructors.

Since you've declared a constructor (and defined it as deleted), you've also gotten rid of the defaulted default constructor.

This rule comes from 12.1p4 in the Standard:

> A default constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument.  **If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted** (8.4).  An implicitly-declared default constructor is an `inline public` member of its class.  A defaulted default constructor for class `X` is deﬁned as deleted if ...

Since default initialization relies on the compiler-declared default constructor, it works if and only if there is no user-declared constructor.

You can fix this by making the default constructor explicitly declared as defaulted, like so:

```
struct test
{
  const int index;
  test(void) = default; // <-- ADD THIS
private:
  test(const test&) = delete;
};
```

But this doesn't work in your situation, the defaulted default constructor is deleted because the rule continues with

> A defaulted default constructor for class X is deﬁned as deleted if ...
>
> - any non-variant non-static data member of `const`-qualified type (or array thereof) with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* does not have a user-provided default constructor,

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: His code doesn't, the title of his question does.  So I'm addressing both...

Comment: IMHO, you should lead with the aggregate initialization part, rather than having that at the end, since there never was any default initialization going on.

Comment: I believe that what the OP meant by "default initialization" was actually "aggregate initialization" (i.e. the method of initialization that is available by default), even if he didn't know the right term for it. Of course, I'm speculating.

Comment: @Praetorian: Reorganized.  Is this better?

Comment: Possibly, yes. I can't find a formal definition for "user-defined function", however.

Comment: @dyp: I fixed that wording in light of your information that the Standard language is "user-provided" not "user-defined".

Comment: Alright, I removed my comment. Didn't downvote, though.

Answer (score 3):

It's a gcc bug, see [Bug 52707 - C++11 Deleted special member function prevent type being an aggregate](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52707) . gcc erroneously thinks the class is not an aggregate any more, if it has a deleted special member function (like a deleted copy constructor).

This seems to have been fixed in g++4.9.0

Comment: Not sure what to write more than that, it's already redundant. See Ben Voigt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. The error states that:

```
no matching function for call to ‘test::test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)
```

which is what you are trying to do.

Because G++ is nice, it lists the possible *candidates*, which include:

```
test::test(const test&) <deleted>
```

It then notes that not only is this deleted, `test arg{1};` will not work because you cannot convert `1` to a `test` object.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.  The fact that I'm declaring a copy constructor (even though as <deleted>) causes the compiler to NOT generate the initializer.